# Bounding the tail of a stretched exponential series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Let there be constants $\alpha>0$ and  $0<\beta<1$. I want to show that, for $n$ sufficiently large
>
> $$\sum_{m=n}^\infty e^{-\alpha m^\beta}\leq c(n) e^{-\alpha n^\beta}$$
> where $c(n)$ is a polinomial.

Context: We know that the tail of a exponentially decaying series decays with the same rate, that is:
$$\sum_{m=n}^\infty e^{-\alpha m} = e^{-\alpha n}\sum_{m=0}^\infty e^{-\alpha m} = e^{-\alpha n}\left(\tfrac{1}{1-e^{-\alpha}}\right)= Ce^{-\alpha n}.$$

Our series is "stretched" exponential because we're working with $a_n = e^{-an^\beta}$ with $\beta<1$. That makes the terms of our series decay slower than exponentially.

According to my supervisor I can't find a constant $C$ so that $\sum_{m=n}^\infty e^{-\alpha m^\beta}\leq Ce^{-\alpha n^\beta}$, but I can find a polinomial that does the job.

So, here's my attempt so far

---

$\sum_{m=n}^\infty e^{-\alpha m^\beta} = e^{-\alpha n^\beta} \sum_{m=n}^\infty e^{-\alpha (m^\beta-n^\beta)}$. Suffice to show that exists $\gamma>0$ such that, for n sufficiently large, $$\sum_{m=n}^\infty e^{-\alpha(m^\beta-n^\beta)}\leq n^\gamma$$

that would imply that exists an $n_0\geq 1$ such that $$\gamma\geq \frac{\log\left(\sum_{m=n}^\infty e^{-\alpha(m^\beta-n^\beta)}\right)}{\log(n)}\; \mbox{ for }n \geq n_0.$$
But, how can I show the sequence $a_n = \tfrac{\log(\sum_{m=n}^\infty e^{-\alpha(m^\beta-n^\beta)})}{\log(n)}$ is bounded?

---

I also attempted to bound the series by an integral to no avail. According to my supervisor I should be able to show this simply by working with the series "brute and simple". Is it actually easy and I'm not seeing it or my supervisor is saying this is easy when it's actually not? (wouldn't be the first time, and I appreciate him for it)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with the integral comparison argument should be a simple way to show the mentioned bound: One has
$$\sum_{k=n}^\infty \exp(-\alpha k^\beta) \leq + \exp(-\alpha n^\beta) + \int_{n}^\infty \exp(-\alpha x^\beta) \, \mathrm{d} x.$$
Now make the change of variables $x^\beta = y$ to get
$$\int_n^\infty \exp(-\alpha x^\beta) \, \mathrm{d} x = \beta^{-1} \int_{n^\beta}^\infty y^{1/\beta-1} \exp(-\alpha y) dy.$$
If $\beta >1$, then (assuming $n \geq 1$) we get
$$\int_{n^\beta}^\infty y^{1/\beta-1} \exp(-\alpha y) dy \leq \int_{n^\beta}^\infty \exp(-\alpha y) dy = \frac{\exp(-\alpha n^\beta)}{\alpha}.$$
If $\beta \in (0,1]$, we introduce $m := \lceil 1/\beta \rceil$ (ceiling function) and find
\begin{equation}
\int_{n^\beta}^\infty y^{1/\beta-1} \exp(-\alpha y) dy \leq \int_{n^\beta}^\infty y^m \exp(-\alpha y) dy = C_{\alpha,m}(n^\beta) \exp(-\alpha n^\beta ),
\end{equation}
where $C_{\alpha,m}$ is a polynomial of degree $m$. (This follows by partial integration.) Since $m \beta \leq 1$, one has $C_{\alpha,\beta}(n^\beta) \ll_{\alpha,\beta} n$. And, yes, you cannot replace this polynomial by a constant (at least in the cases $\beta < 1$), because one has
$$\sum_{k=n}^\infty \exp(-\alpha k^\beta) \geq \int_n^\infty \exp(-\alpha x^\beta) \, dx.$$
Similiar arumgents as above would give a lower bound of similiar kind.

Comment: I believe in your change of variables it should be $y^{\frac{1}{\beta}-1}$. But with a few changes it indeed shows what I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, there is a small mistake. I will correct it.